# Why do i sometime sees text all over editor in putty

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin, putty

I use putty on windows for Linux file editing.

Sometime when i type long commands then i see that text starts appearing either at the beginning of that line "on top of already written text" or sometime at some any remote corner.

But command still gets executed.

How can i fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue due to a malformed $PS1 environment variable. I was having fun getting all cute with the different styles and colors and didn't realize I made a small mistake with the encodings.

Try setting it to a more basic one with this command... `export PS1="\u@\h \w> "`... and check if the issue still happens. If that solves it, then you can fiddle with your usual settings and see if you can correct it.

Hope this helps!